# Instance of class does not initialize IBOutlets in class

Tags: xcode, swift, initialization, iboutlet

I have a class called `AccountPanelController` that contains two variables: an IBOutlet to an `NSTableView`, as well as a simple `Int`. When I run my app, `awakeFromNib:` prints that both the `NSTableView` and the `Int` have been initialized. From another file, I have created and initialized an instance of the class `AcountPanelController`. Via a button connected to that other file, I call `openPanel:` on the instance. At that point `accountTable` does not exist but somehow `number` does. In other words, when I initialize the instance of my class the `Int` is being created, but the `NSTableView`, an IBOutlet, is not. Why is this? I assume it is because `accountTable` is an IBOutlet, and therefore will not reinitialize. What can I do about this? (Xcode Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a), Cocoa, Swift) 
 
Thanks, 
bigelerow

```
class AccountPanelController: NSObject, NSTableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var accountTable: NSTableView!
    var number: Int = 5

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        println(accountTable) // prints "<NSTableView: 0x100512aa0>"
        println(number) // prints "5"
    }

    func openPanel() {
        println(number) // prints "5"
        println(accountTable) // prints "nil"
        accountTable.reloadData() // throws error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
    }

    // NSTableView data source functions below...

}
```

Other File

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject?) {
    var instance = AccountPanelController()
    instance.openPanel()
}
```

Comment: awakeFromNib will only run when AccountPanelController is being instantiated by IB.  In your other file, you are creating a second instance of AccountPanelController, and awakeFromNib will not be called.

Comment: I assume you have a .xib file where you've connected accountTable so it gets initialized by IB for the instance created by IB.

Comment: If this is so, what class is the file's owner for the window that contains accountTable?  In the file's owner class you should be able to create an IBOutlet property to the instance of AccountPanelController created by IB.  No need to create a second instance.

Comment: @jwlaughton The other file is the File's Owner of the xib, and creating an IBOutlet to AccountPanelController did work. Thanks a lot. Do you know why creating a second instance doesn't work though?

Comment: It didn't work because you were creating a second instance of AccountPanelController where the IBOutlet wasn't connected to anything. Your "instance" is a different object than the instance of AccountPanelController instantiated by IB.

Comment: If you want the second instance to know a pointer to to accountTable, you'd need to set it manually because IB is not doing it for you. But why would you want to create two delegates?

Comment: I might assume that the "other" file is a window controller.  If so, you might think about your IBAction in the first file being a lazy instantiation of the "other" file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IB automatically creates instances of all objects with IBOutlets when their xib file is loaded. So, instead of creating my own, second, instance in another file: 
`var instance = AccountPanelController()`

I simply made a reference to the instance IB had already made for me: 
`IBOutlet weak var IBInstance: AcountPanelController!`

Unlike the second instance, this IB created version contained initialized IBOutlets. When I referenced `AccountTable` it was not nil.